# list and restore soft deleted blobs - azure python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to restore multiple blobs in my container.The storage account was enabled with soft delete for 10 days.
I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/undelete-blob) on how to undelete , but I have multiple blobs recursively within directories which are soft deleted

However I failed to find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) via python.

I need to do it in  python to  list and undelete the blobs

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, you could find sdk method in [Python Storage SDK](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html?highlight=undelete#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.undelete_blob) corresponding to the REST API.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import (
    BaseBlobService
)

accountName = "***"
accountKey = "***"
containerName = "***"
blobName = "***"

blobService = BaseBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)

blobService.undelete_blob(containerName, blobName)
```

Comment: for passing the "blobName", how do i list the blobs which are deleted, as there are multiple blobs deleted withing directories. I assume I need to list the deleted blobs and then pass those blobs as "blobName" to the 


       blobService.undelete_blob(containerName, blobName)

Comment: @anudeep Based on my search, there is no such method to list soft delete blob directly in sdk or rest api. You could use `blob.exist()` to judge the truly status of desired blob. Please refer to this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613916/how-to-validate-if-blob-is-exists-or-not-in-deleted-list/52619272#52619272

Comment: @anudeep Hi,any progress?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2):

As Jay mentioned, currently you can't tell Azure Storage REST API to return you only the soft deleted blobs. What you would need to do is list all blobs in a blob container and ask the REST API to include deleted blobs in the listing.

So you would be calling [`list_blobs`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html?highlight=undelete#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.list_blobs) method and for `include` parameter in that method, you would need to specify [`include.DELETED`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.models.html#azure.storage.blob.models.Include.DELETED). The blobs list returned will include deleted blobs.

You would then loop through the blobs and find out which of the blobs are in soft deleted state and will use [`undelete_blob`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html?highlight=undelete#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.undelete_blob) to undelete them.

You also mentioned that you have deleted blobs in subfolders as well. To list all blobs, you will need to specify `delimiter` as empty string. You will then get blobs in sub folders as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, restoring everything soft-deleted:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient


def main():
    sas_url = f"https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}?{SAS}"
    container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)
    blobs_list = container.list_blobs(
        # name_starts_with="my_directory",  # Uncomment if specific directory.
        include="deleted"
    )

    count = 0
    deleted = 0
    for blob in blobs_list:
        if blob.deleted:
            blob_client = container.get_blob_client(blob)
            blob_client.undelete_blob()
            print("Undeleted", blob.name)
            deleted += 1
        count += 1

    print("undeleted", deleted, "blobs out of", count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This code worked for me. Saved the day...

Answer (score 0):

To list and deleted you can use below piece of code. blob_service.list_blobs method with include=Include.DELETED will list all the deleted as well as undeleted blobs. To traverse the inside the directory use delimiter = ''.
Furthur more, if there are a lot more files in the blob then you can use a marker to page through all the results.

```
def restoreBlobs():
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME, account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
    next_marker = None
    while True:
        blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINERNAME, prefix=reverseSettledFolder, include=Include.DELETED, delimiter='', marker=next_marker, timeout=None)
        for blob in blobs:
            blob_service.undelete_blob(CONTAINERNAME, blob_name=blob.name, timeout=None)
            next_marker = blobs.next_marker
            if not next_marker:
                break
    print ("done")
```