# How to check existence of soft deleted file in Azure blob container with node js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have file which was stored in some Azure blob directory "folder1/folder2/file.txt". This file was soft deleted - I can see it in Azure web console. I need to have function which checks this file existence.

1. I tried library "azure-storage". It perfectly works with NOT removed files:

```
const blobService = azure.createBlobService(connectingString);
blobService.doesBlobExist(container, blobPath, callback)
```

May be anyone knows how use same approach with soft removed files?

2. I tied with lib "@azure/storage-blob".
   But I stuck with endless entities there (BlobServiceClient, ContainerItem, BlobClient, ContainerClient, etc) and couldn't find way to see particular file in particular blob directory.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-delete-javascript#restore-soft-deleted-objects-when-versioning-is-disabled), I got to restore the Soft deleted blobs and their names with the below code snippet.

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const  connstring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=kvpstorageaccount;AccountKey=<Storage_Account_Key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

if (!connstring) throw  Error('Azure Storage Connection string not found');
const  blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connstring);

async  function  main(){
const  containerName = 'kpjohncontainer';
const  blobName = 'TextFile05.txt';
const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
undeleteBlob(containerClient, blobName)

}

main()
.then(() =>  console.log(`done`))
.catch((ex) =>  console.log(ex.message));

async  function  undeleteBlob(containerClient, blobName){

const  blockBlobClient = await  containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
await  blockBlobClient.undelete(); //to restore the deleted blob

console.log(`undeleted blob ${blobName}`);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

To check if the blob exists and if exists but in Soft-deleted state, I found the relevant [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52619325/16630138) but it’s in C# provided by @*Gaurav Mantri*. To achieve the same in NodeJS refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53361724).